# Django REST Framework: static file serve does not work only when the url is "static/"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following `urls.py` -

```
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', include("admin.urls")),
                  path('accounts/', include("accounts.urls")),
                  path('blogs/', include("blogs.urls")),
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In the `settings.py` I have -

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

Here my static files in the static folder are showing a "Page Not Found (404)" error when opened in the browser by using the link `"http://localhost:8000/static/style.css"`. But if I change `settings.STATIC_URL` to anything else, it works. For example, if I do - `static("anything/", document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`, then it works on "http://localhost:8000/anything/style.css", only the strings that start with 'static' does not work.

I tried removing all URLs and only keeping the `static()` to see if other URLs are interfering with static, but it still shows the same error.

In short : It does not work if I use STATIC_URL defined in settings.py in the static() function. Any other strings works.

Can anyone shed some light on this behaviour?

Comment: What is the full path to the folder where your static files are located? And show how you refer static files in templates and the url you're opening in browser to check if static files work.

Comment: I am not using it in templates, only opening it in the browser. I added more information. Static files are located in the static folder of the root directory. Basically, anything string as the URL of the static files works, except the URL in settings.py

Comment: Somewhere in your code there is another url pattern which handles `static/` url and it is broken.

Comment: It is actually not the `static/` endpoint specifically, it's any endpoint that's defined to be STATIC_ROOT in settings.py. Also, I tried removing all URLs from root urls.py and only keeping the static one. It still does not work.

Comment: Somewhere in your code there is another URL pattern which handles `settings.STATIC_URL` and it has precedence over urlpatterns listed in the question and that view/static handler is broken. Or your story lacks significant technical details. If `static("anything/", document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` works then there is no other possible obstacle to `settings.STATIC_URL` utilization unless it is already used elsewhere.